# Any way to connect an azure function with azure table storage

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

i have an azure function with http trigger, then this function get data from url and process this data and parse to json.

What i need is when the function is called before return the answer store this data into azure table storage.

```
const axios = require('axios');
const azureStorage = require('azure-storage');
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
    const name = (req.query.url || (req.body && req.body.url));
    const responseMessage = name
        ? `Hello you are trying to download file from ${req.body.name} with url ${req.body.url}`
        : "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.";
    context.res = {
        body: {
            textParsed: await getData(req.body.url),
            statusTable: saveDataOnTable(context),
            conectionString: process.env.conectionString
        }
    };
}

async function getData(url) {
    const request = await axios(url).then(response => { return response.data });
    const jsonData = await csvJSON(request);
    return jsonData;
}

async function csvJSON(csv) {
    let regularQuotes = /"/g;
    let csvArray = csv.split("\r\n");
    let headers = csvArray[0].split(",");
    let result = [];

    //recorre el array con los datos del csv
    for (let index = 1; index < csvArray.length; index++) {
        //comprueba que el campo no este vacio
        if (!csvArray[index]) continue;
        let obj = {};
        //guarda la linea actual
        let currentline = csvArray[index];
        //reemplaza los caracteres de escape como comillas
        currentline = regularQuotes[Symbol.replace](currentline, '');
        //separa los datos utilizando las comillas como caracter de escape
        currentline = currentline.split(",");
        for (let j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
            //elimina espacios de las cabezeras
            let head = headers[j].trim();
            //elimina espacios de los datos
            let value = currentline[j].trim();
            //crea el objeto con los valores
            obj[head] = value;
        }
        result.push(obj);
    }
    //devuelve una string en formato json
    return JSON.stringify(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- There is sdk available to connect and manipulate a table in azure called `@azure/data-tables`.
  Install it along with `uuid`

```
npm install @azure/data-tables 
npm install uuid
```

- Import specific functions from the sdk such as:

```
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
const { TableClient, AzureNamedKeyCredential } = require("@azure/data-tables");
```

- Now you will need the connection key of your storage entity. Also please create a table beforehand in that storage space.

```
const accountname = "";
const accountkey = "";
const tableName = "";
```

- Now we create a `tableclient` which will connect to the table storage and add the entity to the table.

```
const  credential = new  AzureNamedKeyCredential(accountname, accountkey);

const  client = new  TableClient(`https://${accountname}.table.core.windows.net`, tableName, credential);
```

- Now we have to create an entity which will be send to the table and then we will send it to table storage.

```
// I am assuming that the response of the url isin json

let  testjsonobject = {};
testjsonobject.language = "javascript";
testjsonobject.platform = "azure functions"
context.log(testjsonobject);
let  testjsonobjectString = JSON.stringify(testjsonobject);


let  partitionkeynew = uuidv4();;//crypto.randomUUID();
context.log(partitionkeynew);

  

const  entity = {
    partitionKey :  partitionkeynew,
    rowKey:"1",
    description:testjsonobjectString
}

let  result = await  client.createEntity(entity);
```

complete code :

```
const { TableServiceClient, odata } = require("@azure/data-tables");
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
const { TableClient, AzureNamedKeyCredential } = require("@azure/data-tables");

  
  

module.exports = async  function (context, req) {

context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
const  accountkey = "";
const  accountname = "";
const  tableName = "";

const  credential = new  AzureNamedKeyCredential(accountname, accountkey);
const  client = new  TableClient(`https://${accountname}.table.core.windows.net`, tableName, credential);

let  testjsonobject = {};
testjsonobject.language = "javascript";
testjsonobject.platform = "azure functions"
context.log(testjsonobject);
let  testjsonobjectString = JSON.stringify(testjsonobject);


let  partitionkeynew = uuidv4();;//crypto.randomUUID();
context.log(partitionkeynew);


const  entity = {
    partitionKey :  partitionkeynew,
    rowKey:"1",
    description:testjsonobjectString
}

let  result = await  client.createEntity(entity);
context.log(result);


context.res = {
// status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
body:  result
};

}
```

Here result will get a Etag if the operation is successful.

[image]

[image]